# this.Hide() not working in new projects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've always used `this.Hide` in `Form1_Load(...)` when I needed to and it has always worked. But now in a new project, `this.Hide` does not work anywhere and this is the only code I have!

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false;
    this.Hide();
}
```

Why doesn't the Form Hide?

Comment: The real question is: why do you want to hide something when you are showing it? Smells bad. You surely don't need to call `Show`/`ShowDialog` if you are not intending to show form.

Comment: @Sinatr no need to be paranoid. It prevents you from seeing genuinely good intentions.

Comment: Good intentions can be painfully implemented. I am still curious why do you need to hide form in `Form1_Load(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working as you call it in the Load. The load happens before it actually becomes visible, so you can't hide it from there either.

Also you should search before asking:

[why isn't this.Hide() working in Form1_load event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003587/why-isnt-this-hide-working-in-form1-load-event)

[Hiding forms on startup: why doesn't this.Hide() hide my form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769337/hiding-forms-on-startup-why-doesnt-this-hide-hide-my-form)

Comment: +1 for explaining why it won't work with Load() rather that providing just the piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

The `Load` event is too early to hide the `Form` since it isn't shown yet then.

When overriding the `OnShown` method it does work for me:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);

    this.Visible = false;
    this.Hide();
}
```

Or, of course, create a handler for the `Shown` event.

Either of the two calls is good. You don't need both.

Comment: You don't need even to override OnShown, just put the this.Hide(); in the handler!

Comment: Of course. I think of this being the better solution overall, that's why I wanted to give another POV.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dece45c8-9076-497e-9414-8cd9b34f572f/how-to-start-a-form-in-hidden-mode?forum=winforms):

```
private bool mShowAllowed;
protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
{
    if (!mShowAllowed) value = false;
    {
        base.SetVisibleCore(value); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply hide in the `Shown` event of the Form1:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know I can do that, but if you hide it in the Shown event, 90% of the time you see the form flash before it gets hidden. Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is working.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Opacity = 0;
}
```