# Hide Windows form from everywhere (taskbar, task switcher, etc)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have Windows Application form I need to hide `Form` on `form_Load` event and it should be hidden from task bar and also from task switcher (i.e. when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>). means it would not be showing anywhere .

Comment: if you don't want the user to interact with it, why not just create a console application instead of a windows form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding forms on startup: why doesn't this.Hide() hide my form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769337/hiding-forms-on-startup-why-doesnt-this-hide-hide-my-form)

Answer (score 0):

So you should try this:

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowInTaskbar = false;
    Hide();
}
```

`ShowInTaskbar` indicates wether your `Form` should appear in the task bar.

To hide it from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> I found [this solution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17893626/5528593):

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        var Params = base.CreateParams;
        Params.ExStyle |= 0x80;
        return Params;
    }
}
```

Simply overwrite the `CreateParams` property of your `Form` as shown above.

**UPDATE** The order of events when opening a `Form` leads to the problem that your visibility is restored after the `Load` event. So you will need to overwrite something like this:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);
    // if you still want to hide
    Hide();
}
```

Comment: its working but form is still showing on main window.

Comment: @vyaskarnavkumar So @user1666620 was right. Your solution lies in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8549250/5528593 Some framework code tries to keep you `Visible`, so with this overridden `OnVisibleChanged` the above code will work.