# OCX Event is not fired when parent is not set to a visible form

Tags: c#, events, service, ocx

I have an OCX and I use it in a Service and There is no visible form.
It needs a form as a parent otherwise it's events is not fired 
How can I make the ocx to process messages and fire the event ?

Here is my code :

```
public AxKylixSMS SMS;

SMS = new AxKylixSMS();            

SMS.CreateControl();

SMS.NewDeliveryReport += new   _DKylixSMSEvents_NewDeliveryReportEventHandler(OnDeliveryReport);
```

OnDeliveryReport Event is not fired. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Almost any ActiveX control needs a host window to come alive.  A typical failure mode of not hosting it is that it refuses to raise events.  The message loop started by Application.Run() is also crucial.  You can hide the window it lives in, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3742980/17034

Answer (score 0):

use this to reference your form
try :

```
public AxKylixSMS SMS;

SMS = new AxKylixSMS();            

SMS.CreateControl();

SMS.NewDeliveryReport += new   _DKylixSMSEvents_NewDeliveryReportEventHandler(this.OnDeliveryReport);
```

Comment: No Difference using "this" keyword . the event is fired when a form as parent is set , with the same code and by the way there is no form.

Comment: You use an ocx but this ocx is embedded on a service , what service please?

Comment: No I am writing a Windows Service and I use OCX in that service.

Answer (score 0):

Usually ocx are made to work on winform but in your context you can communicate between your windows service and your winform using EventLog which is accessible by both:
here a sample
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4857/A-realtime-event-log-monitoring-tool