# Run a program as a process in the background

Tags: c#

I want to create a program that won't close when you click the close button but, only when a exit function is run from within the form.
I was thinking i could have it run in the background without the window needing to be open (Like the steam client and dropbox, mediafire, google drive, google chrome extension notification), and was wondering how to do that.
I was thinking of some ways to do it but i wasn't sure how to do them:

- A starter program that keeps it open in the background
- Running a background process that keeps information stored

I am running c# 2010 so i will need answers relating to that. I would also prefer to not use 3rd party extensions/tools except a basic text editor(Notepad++).
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make it as a service instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible options:

1. [Hide the main form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3742709/102937)
2. [Create a Tray application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995195/how-can-i-make-a-net-winforms-application-that-only-runs-in-the-system-tray)
3. [Write a Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx)