# DataGridView AutoResizeColumns before the Form is displayed

Tags: datagridview, autoresize

It's a simple question:

```
Public Sub ShowListar()

    '... "lista" is my DataGridView. Also it is a UserControl.
    lista.Listar() '... Here I fill my DataGridView and call AutoResizeColumns

    Me.ShowModal()

End Sub
```

The AutoResizeColumns is called before the form is displayed, and therefore the DataGridView doesnot autoresize the columns. But When I call AutoResizeColumns with the Form beying displayed, the AutoResize works well.

There is a way to make AutoResizeColumns work before I call "Me.ShowModal()" ???

Comment: From my experience, properties are defaulted until the form is visible.  Hans Passant gives a great answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3742980/3773066) explaining how a form comes to exist.  Given his code example, if you use the VB equivalent, you might be able to accomplish your goal.  But I don't know the specifics of how that would work, just the theoretical idea.

Comment: Interesting. I think I can somehow dig a workaround from that.