# Does windows /f teminate processes on shutdown?

Tags: c#, windows, process

I am using the following code to handle `taskkill` on my process:

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
private class TestMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == /*WM_CLOSE*/ 0x10)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I'm shutting down");
            var mailService = new MailService();
            mailService.SendEmail("Test from application exit");
            //Application.Exit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.AddMessageFilter(new TestMessageFilter());
    Application.Run();
}
```

The `MessageBox` pops up and the email is sent when I do `taskkill /im MyProcess.exe`. However this does not happen on windows shutdown.

Does Windows kill processes forcefully on shutdown or is it me who's missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That you can see WM_CLOSE at all in an IMessageFilter is quite accidental and an implementation detail of taskkill.exe.  You normally only see *posted* messages, WM_CLOSE is normally sent.  I think you see taskkill.exe first trying to ask nicely, only using the sledge-hammer when the app doesn't respond fast enough.  Task Manager used to do this as well but doesn't anymore in later Windows versions.

And no, it certainly can't work on a Windows shutdown.  It *sends* a WM_QUERYENDSESSION message to a window to announce the shutdown.

Lots of good reasons to make this a service instead.  But as long as you want to do it this way then you need a window to see that message.  Subscribe its FormClosing event, the e.CloseReason property tells you why it is closing down.  You'll see `CloseReason.WindowsShutDown`.  You just need to keep the window invisible to keep it equivalent to what you have, override the SetVisibleCore() method as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742980/17034).

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern operating systems use is to request that running processes terminate gracefully, then kill them if they don't terminate within a timeout. Some applications will pop up a save changes prompt on shutdown, but they may not actually appear to the user - Windows can display a "shutting down" screen and say that some processes are still running - do you want to kill them and shut down anyway?

I believe if you're using Windows Forms you can achieve the same result as you have here with the Closing/Closed events*, so you could see if either of those fire by saving some text to a file (and make sure to flush it), and also see if you get any other message codes in PreFilterMessage in the same way.

*You could get either Closing or Closed or both, so check both. e.g. you can get a Closed without a prior Closing.