# How To Run C# Executable under Background Process, Not in App

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, taskmanager

On Windows 10, `Task Manager` separates running processes into 3 different categories: Apps, Background Processes and Windows Processes. When I compile and run my C# executable, it's located under `Apps` section in the Task Manager. However, I want to run it under `Background Processes` section.

I tried to use `this.ShowInTaskbar = false;` but it's not working on Windows 10.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742980/17034

Comment: yes that's fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a background process and an app, in the eyes of the task manager, is that the latter has at least one visible window, and the former does not. So, make sure that you don't have any visible windows and your process will be placed in the background process category.

Comment: I tried to use invisible window via setting opacity to 0, but no luck. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: That's not an invisible window. Not sure what GUI framework you are using, or how many windows you have, so can't tell you the precise code you need. But it's usually something like `form.Visible = false` although it's probably more complex if you are using WPF

Comment: Of course, the other thing you could do is not create a window at all.

Comment: In WPF it's going to be `form.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden`, which you can of course set at design time

Comment: I get "Form does not contain a definition for 'Visibility'" error.

Comment: I guess you aren't using WPF then are you? I don't really want to try to guess what UI framework you are using. That's no fun. Surely you know. In any case, if you want a background app, why are you even creating a window?