# TaskBar and form visible relationship in WinForms Application C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have windows form frmMain in C# windows application. I set showintaskbar property true in form properties. On form load event, based on condition form will be visible true or false.

When form visible property is set to false, form is visible.

I want to know why the form is visible even though It's visibility property is set to false and showintaskbar is set to true. How both are related?

Programmatically I handled hiding the form using delegates but I want to know the reason.

Comment: When a Form is configured to show in the TaskBar, when you hide it the TaskBar icon is also hidden -- *Programmatically I handled hiding the form using delegates*: post that code, as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hiding a form in its own Load event handler is useless. It's not visible at that point anyway and it's going to become visible when the event handler completes. One has to wonder why you're calling Show on a firm you don't want shown in the first place.

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742709/this-visible-is-not-working-in-windows-forms) answer your question?

Comment: As parallel with @jmcilhinney, it does not make sense for me to try to hide a form in its `Load` event handler. You may want to redesign your form opening logic, i.e. decide if the form will be visible or not within the form that opens the aforementioned form.

Comment: I want to know the reason or relation between Show in taskbar property and form visible property.

Comment: I want to hide a form using property visible as false or this.hide  . When showintaskbar is set to false then only it is hiding. When form is invisible mode, I  have to set few form properties. May I know the reason. Any help is appreciated.