# Hide main form C# on autorun

Tags: c#, winforms, hide, autorun

I found a realy simple method online that allows me to hide the main form in my application:

- Create a console application
- Set output type to Windows Forms Applications

This works perfectly when I run the application either from debugging in visual studio or manually.

However..

I have also set this application to auto start with windows (Windows 7 in this case), so I don't have to start it manually every time. When this happens there is a very very very short moment in which I can still see a full screen form blink. Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

Edit: People seem to missing one important thing.
The project is created as a Console Application, so it has **no Form or Application.Run()** method. It just has a single static Main method like any other Console Application.

Edit2: Just out of interest, should I rather make a normal WinForms project and try to hide that Main window using either a suggested answer or other sollution?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Single Form Hide on Startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272/single-form-hide-on-startup)

Comment: Do you need form at all, or you only need your exe to be run and unseen?

Comment: @Daniel, the application has no form, yet it still shows one for a split second at system boot. The desired result is an unseen exe (it's ok if it shows up in the task manager).

Comment: Occam's razor says that you are seeing output from *another* process that gets started at login.  Use msconfig and temporary disable everything other than yours.

Comment: I added something as an answer, maybe it can help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are probably seeing is the command window appear and disappear.

I would recommend creating it either as a form and then following what Jeffery suggested or create and install it as a [service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) that starts each time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You'd think the command window would pop up, but I'm fairly sure it's a WinForms window, as it's white. Weird huh?

Answer (score 3):

The [`Application.Run(Form)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902.aspx) method makes the supplied form visible.  Create the form with its [`Visible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx) property initially set to `false`, and use the no-argument [`Application.Run()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900.aspx) in your main loop.

Comment: @SaphuA You don't have a user32 message loop on your main thread at all?  I wonder if that may be a factor.  Try calling `Application.DoEvents()` at the top of your `Main`; does that have any effect on its behavior?

Answer (score 3):

i just tested this:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.Hide();
    }
```

also set

```
this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Answer (score 2):

The main form cannot be hidden directly. After the form load it must do something.

Something like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
  {
    progressBar1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    progressBar1.Value = i;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40);
    if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
    {
      Form12 f1 = new Form12();
      f1.Show();
    }
  }
  this.Opacity = 0;
  this.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It's hard to understand what you mean and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Try to hide the app from the task bar as well.

To do that please use this code.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   {
    Visible = false; // Hide form window.
    ShowInTaskbar = false; // Remove from taskbar.
    Opacity = 0;

    base.OnLoad(e);
   }
```

Thanks.
Ruhul

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Application.Run(new MainForm())
```

do whatever you have to do, without any form.  Your app won't be shown anywhere.