# How to active window

Tags: c#, registry, exe

I work on C#.I have an application .In this application I need to show message ,suppose in 1pm my application show “Take dinner”.In 4 pm show “Take snacks ”,Basically it’s a reminder application ,Here user set time and message,duration how long it’s become active on window .I already write this application ,But problem is User have one special requirement ,User don’t like to see the **application icon on quick bar /start-->programFiles**,Application just take position on registry .User when start his os it’s become active and at the exact time it’s just show the message ,after the interval duration become invisible. If have any query plz ask.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the exe in the startup folder either in the Start menu under the startup folder or in the registry.  The registry path is as follows:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

That will start it when the user logs on.  Then, have the application start hidden (Form.Visible = false).  When it is time, make the application visible again.

Comment: thanks for reply.I have the application but how can i periodically visible and invisible  the application .will you plz show some syntax.thanks

Comment: If you are using Winforms, just do a this.visible = false; when you want to hide the form.  To show it again, set it to true.

Comment: i work on winform.I write this.visible=false on from constructor,But form become visible,But if i write under the button event it's become invisible.Why this occur

Comment: Add the code under the form_Loaded event.  This will ensure that everything else the form is doing in the background is complete before your code runs.

Comment: On the main form, create a Load event.  In that event, put the code "this.Visible = false;"

Comment: How to write on registry. or write on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Comment: To write to the registry from C#, here is a good link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927152/way-to-write-on-registry-location  If you want to do it manually, you can create a reg file and then run it on the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the exe in the startup folder either in the Start menu under the startup folder or in the registry. The registry path is as follows:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

using System.Windows.Forms;

```
namespace HideWindows
{
    public class HideForm : Form
    {
        public HideForm()
        {
            Opacity = 0;
            ShowInTaskbar = false;
        }

        public new void Show()
        {
            Opacity = 100;
            ShowInTaskbar = true;

            Show(this);
        }
    }
}
```

[Single Form Hide on Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272/single-form-hide-on-startup)
Above url help  more.

Comment: You would suggest it to yourself?

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered converting the application to a [windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx)?  If you did this, you could have it run in the background automatically without any need for user interaction.

Comment: The problem with a service is that it shouldn't interact with the user (big no no).

Comment: @BiggsTRC agreed..  my thought was that the service would act more as a *dispatcher* with a separate UI used to manage it.  It would also be possible to create a desktop application that did not appear on the task bar or notification area, but management becomes difficult.