# Way to write on registry location

Tags: c#, windows, registry

work on C# window application.I want to write on registry.i know how to write on registry.I use bellow syntax to write on registry.

```
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
        key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.cre.CreateSubKey("asb");
        key.SetValue("asb", "Isabella");
        key.Close();
```

But problem is i fail to write on specified location .**i want to write on bellow location**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

On this location want to add string **value="abc"** and **ValueData="efd"**
If have any query plz ask.thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Windows version does this fail on? At a guess it is failing and giving you an ACCESS_DENIED on Vista and Win7?

Comment: Usually it falls to installers to write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For HKCU:

```
string keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, true);
rk.SetValue("abc", "efd");
rk.Close();
```

For HKLM you need to do it with administrative privileges.  That requires adding a manifest to your program to invoke the UAC prompt on Vista or Win7.

Answer (score 2):

Writing to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` requires administrative privileges. And if you're running on Windows Vista or 7, it also requires process elevation, lest you run afoul of UAC (User Account Control).

The best thing is *only* to write to this registry key during installation (where you will have full administrative privileges). You should only *read* from it once your application is installed.

Save all regular settings under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. Use the [`Registry.CurrentUser` field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.currentuser.aspx) to do that. Or, better yet, abandon the registry altogether and [save your application's settings in a config file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx). Visual Studio has built-in support for this, it's very simple to do from C#. The registry is no longer the recommended way of saving application state.

Answer (score 2):

```
RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine.
                  OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);

// set value of "abc" to "efd" 
reg.SetValue("abc", "efd", RegistryValueKind.DWord);

// get value of "abc"; return 0 if value not found 
string value = (string)reg.GetValue("abc", "0");
```