# How to hide WinForm after it run?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, hide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Single Form Hide on Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272/single-form-hide-on-startup)

I want to hide my WinForm after it run (Not minimizing).

I used:

```
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
    }
```

But it's not working. Can you help me do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "run"?

Comment: When I open my app at Windows Explorer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the form Load override you can use one of the following tricks:

1. Make the form completely transparent:

   ```
   private void OnFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        Form form = (Form)sender;
        form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        form.Opacity = 0;
   }
   ```
2. Move the form way off the screen:

   ```
   private void OnFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Form form = (Form)sender;
       form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
       form.Location = new Point(-10000, -10000);
   }
   ```

Comment: Sometimes the Opacity=0 may not work if you are hosting some weird control.  You can set it to form.Opacity = 0.01.

Answer (score 5):

Try to hide the form after it has been shown and not after it has been loaded, use the **Shown** event instead of the **Load** event

Comment: Yeah, Try this code to hide.

     protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
        Visible = false; // Hide form window.
        ShowInTaskbar = false; // Remove from taskbar.
        Opacity = 0;

            base.OnLoad(e);
         }

Answer (score 4):

You can't easily hide the form but what you can do is set the Opacity to 0, for example:

```
this.Opacity = 0;
```

If you Don't want the user to be able to see the app at all set this:

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Then they won't be able to see the form in the task bar and it will be invisible.

I believe this solved your "no use minimized" requirement??

Comment: I think Pavel and my answers are the same here ...