# How to make an app just for background running in C# Windows application

Tags: c#, windows

I have to make a Windows Forms application just for background running, I don't want to show anything, I just have to connect to a MySQL database and show notifications thrown at it.

Comment: [Create a Worker Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers) or [Create a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer#:~:text=Create%20a%20Service%201%20From%20the%20Visual%20Studio,and%20then%20select%20OK.%20...%20.%20See%20More.)

Comment: is there any way to just hide form completly

Comment: By default, there is no form in a service (so no need to hide anything)

Comment: Yes you can hide a form by using  Hide(); in startup method, please take a look at this link  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455084/how-to-hide-winform-after-it-run