# Commandline utility, which show OSD

Tags: c#, nativewindow

I'm newbe in c#.

I coding command line utility, which show OSD (floating text on the screen) only.
What the best practice for that ?

What project better use for me: console application or windows form or other....
And.... if console application - how hide console ?

If windows form - how hide form (maybe set transparent , I don't know)

Please explain this nuances and give advices if possible...

I'm using visual c# 2010

Thanks

Comment: Your questions essentially asks someone to give you the whole implementation which is too much of an ask when you can discover most of what you need in a simple google search.

Comment: How about first writing some code and than asking *"I did this but have a problem at this"* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I googled , and find this helpful topics:

[Single Form Hide on Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272/single-form-hide-on-startup)

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/get-command-line-arguments-in-a-windows-forms-application/