# How to hide window from taskbar in C# Console

Tags: c#, console, window, hide, taskbar

I needed to make an application that doesn’t show any window.
I couldn't find the answer  Also I looked at stack overflow pages.

Comment: Create non-console application without window.

Comment: While using c# forms i can do that from properties

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/70296/2180344

Comment: Thanks for your interest but i dont have Application.Run(new MainForm());

Comment: Make a new Windows Forms app and you will ...

Comment: Alex My project runs in console Why should i use windows form?

Comment: Guys i tried your solutions but it didnt work

Comment: Btw what does non console mean?

Answer (score 0):

Does your application require a user interface? If not, you should really be creating a console application rather than a Windows Forms or WPF Application.

If you simply want to hide a form from within the form you can type the following:

```
this.Hide();
```

**Edit:**
From a console application, you'll want to compile the project as a Windows Forms application under the project properties. Ensure that you have no startup object selected.

Comment: Thanks Fil but i am writing on c# console