# Launch .exe without launching winform UI

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform application UI in c#. I have to now launch the .exe such that it runs in background but does not launch the UI. I have no idea as to how to do it. What changes should I make?

Comment: So is it suppose to work like a service?

Comment: yes..but it should execute manually and not when windows is started

Comment: You have to start it somewhere.

Comment: Either in startup, with batch file, as a service or something like that

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

In the Main window(`Main.cs`) , so the app starts with  minimized windows state, this can also be set in the properties windows of the main window, set value  `Minimized` for the property `WindowState` also add

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

to avoid being shown in task bar

Answer (score 0):

Your app won't work if you don't launch you form.
If you want to hide the form, just use the method Form.Hide().
Besides, this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272/single-form-hide-on-startup) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Form1 Obj = new Form1

You can use

```
Obj.Hide()
```

or 
you can write in Form1 constructor

```
this.visible = false
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can hide the form and still have your app running in background.
- You can set `opacity` to 0 and `ShowInTaskbar` to `false` and still running
  your app in background.