# Form gets disposed when trying to hide it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to hide my main form on a certain event and then show it again later. The problem is that the form gets disposed when I hide it.

**My code for hiding the form:**

```
private void MessageRecived(object sender)
{
    //Do stuff

    if (status == NetConnectionStatus.Connected)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
    else if (status == NetConnectionStatus.Disconnected)
    {
        this.Show();
    }

    //Do some more stuff
}
```

When the "this.Show()" method is called, the following exception is thrown:

> System.ObjectDisposedException
>
> Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.

I have also tried to use "this.Visible = false" and "this.SetVisibleCore(false)" but I get the same result.

**How can I hide the form without it getting disposed?**

**EDIT:**

I found my mistake: There was an object in my code that referenced the form, and it closed it. Thanks to Justin Harvey who pointed out that something else is using the form.

Comment: Unrelated, but you're not checking for equality in your if statements, you're assigning status. Change those to `status == NetConnectionStatus.Connected` and `status == NetConnectionStatus.Disconnected`. Also, what is happening in `//Do stuff` and `// Do some more stuff`, as `Control.Hide` does not dispose by design.

Comment: It is not the hiding that is disposing it, can you show the code that uses the form?

Comment: @AlexGravely you are correct, I will fix it

Comment: yea when is `MessageRecived` called?

Comment: The only other code that uses the form is a button click that connects to a server

Comment: The MessageRecived is called when the application recives a message from a remote server

Comment: Does the form open as hidden? Chances are that the handle isn't created if that's the case.

Comment: You can look at this link [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3742980/3206674](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3742980/3206674) and also [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272/single-form-hide-on-startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272/single-form-hide-on-startup)

Comment: @BarryO'Kane The form is opend shown

Comment: You should create a [mcve] that demostrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your form is Disposed by Garbage Collector or by some other code.
Setup breakpoint in

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
```

method (usualy inside `NAME.Designer.cs` file)

I've made the following experiment and it works well!

1. Create new WindwsForms Application
2. Place Time on main form in Form Designer
3. Add `FormClosing`event handler
4. Add Time `Tick` event handler
5. Write the following code:

   ```
   private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {
       if (MessageBox.Show("Press Yes to Hide only the Form?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) ==
           DialogResult.Yes)
       {
           e.Cancel = true;
           timer1.Enabled = true;
           Hide();
       }
   }

   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Show();
       timer1.Enabled = false;
   }
   ```

Comment: Helped me to track down the issue - There was an object that referenced the form and disposed it.