# Make form invisible

Tags: c#, winforms

I know this question seems very simple but its not working for me, i think i changed a property by accident so the form wont go invisible.

on load, i have :

```
this.Visible = false;
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
this.ShowIcon = false;
```

it doesnt show in taskbar or the icon but for some reason its still visible like in the image below

[image]

i know thats the form because i changed the color to red and it turned red

Comment: set `this.Opacity = 0;`

Comment: why you are using a form when you are going to hide it? perhaps this link will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272/single-form-hide-on-startup

Comment: Do you mean at __runtime__ or in the __desigener__??. For the first: your code is fine, for the second: neither possible nor reasonable!

Comment: The Load event fires *because* you made it visible.  Usually by calling Show().  You can't undo what was done.  Don't call Show().

Comment: Why are you calling `Show()` on a form you dont want to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you can do:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Opacity = 0; //Add this line.
    this.Visible = false;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    this.ShowIcon = false;
}
```

Comment: that worked, im still curious as to what i did that was making it show as this.visible should of worked

Comment: Visible won't do anything in the Loaded event.

Comment: This answer will make the form invisible rather than hidden.  If that's what you wanted, it's a nice answer.

Comment: @Will easy, `Load` event will get called when the form is shown (and it'll be shown only -after- executing the `Load` event handlers). Personally, I prefer minimizing the window (and not show in taskbar) or just don't `Show` it for a start, rather than set the opacity at 0, but your choice.

Comment: @KiNeTiC the OP wants the Form to be Invisible :)

Comment: Your code make the form transparent, but it will still be visible (the Visible property will be true).

Comment: @KiNeTiC sure...I'll better remove that comment and set the visibility to false `this.Visible = false;` :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to hide the form, you can use :

```
this.Hide();
```

Comment: just added that to the form load, the form is still visable

Comment: Move it to the Shown event.  You can't expect to hide a form that has yet to be displayed.