# Hide Form1, show Form2 on Form1_Load

Tags: c#, winforms

The Form1 of my App is a login page that i want to:
- show on some conditions
- hide and show Form2 on some conditions

I can hide/show a form by the button click event like so,

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2= new Form2();
        f2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

> but the same technique does not work for Form1_Load.

I have tried the first example in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272/single-form-hide-on-startup),

**Program.cs**

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run();
    }
```

**Form1**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form2 f2= new Form2();
        f2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

but it's not showing neither Form1 or Form2, and i don't see how it could. The second example i can't understand how i can implement, and the next google results are even more confusing.
Please help i'm stuck on this for 2 hours.

Comment: It should be: `Application.Run(new Form1());` in program.cs

Comment: That is the default way. But doing `this.Hide()` on Form1_Load does not hide the Form1.

Comment: Your program needs to create and load `Form1`. Default or not; you'll need a `new Form1` and a `Show` somewhere. `Application.Run` normally handles this in the right way. An alternative is to create a `Form1` in your main function. Beware that `.Show` is a non-blocking call and your application will exit if you don't handle that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last line in program.cs you must type `new Form1()` between the parenthesis. So, your program.cs code is as follow:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

C# can not hide form in form_load evant Apparently.
To resolve Hide problem, you can use of a timer and hide the form in tick event. i.e.:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

private void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Enabled = false;
    this.Hide();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timerTick);
   timer.Interval = 10;
   Form2 frm = new Form2();
   frm.Show();
   timer.Enabled = true;
 }
```

This works. I tested it.

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: I know what you are saying, but this does not fix my problem.

Comment: @Cris: As it might not resolve your issue immediately, this issue also needs to be addressed.

Comment: I implemented your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hello You Can Use This

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2= new Form2();
    if(condition==true)
    {
        this.Hide();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, thanks! I did make one change though. I put the code above in the Form1_Shown event because I didn't want to click a button in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you reverse the order of your forms? Start with the main form in the main method.

```
Application.Run(new Form2());
```

Now in the constructor of Form2 call the login form with ShowDialog and set the result of the login in a global variable inside the Form2

```
public class Form2:Form
{
     private bool _isValidated = false;
     public Form2()
     {
         InitializeComponent();

         // Add here the conditions to check if you don't want to 
         // run the login process...
         // if(loginNotRequired) 
         //    _isValidated = true;
         // else 

         using(Form1 fLogin = new Form1())
         {
             // This blocks until the user clicks cancel or ok buttons
             DialogResult dr = fLogin.ShowDialog();
             if(dr == DialogResult.OK)
                _isValidated  = true;
         }
     }
```

Now in the Form2.Load event check the status of your login and close the Form2 if the login is not successful

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
         if(!_isValidated)
            this.Close();
         else
            .....
    }
```